# org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.11.0:testCompile failed: For input string: "1.8"

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin

started a new project and refuse to compile :/
Give the below error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.11.0:testCompile (default-testCompile) on project example: **Execution default-testCompile of goa
l org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin:3.11.0:testCompile failed: For input string: "1.8" -> [Help 1]**
[ERROR]
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

here my class:

```
package com.abc.example;

import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class ExampleApplication implements CommandLineRunner
{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(ExampleApplication .class, args);
        System.out.println("Hello 1");
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception
    {
        System.out.println("Hello 2");
    }
}
```

and here part  of my **pom.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.2.0</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.abc</groupId>
    <artifactId>example</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>example</name>
    <description>example</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-j</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <excludes>
                        <exclude>
                            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
                            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
                        </exclude>
                    </excludes>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

**Java version:**

java version "1.8.0_171"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_171-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.171-b11, mixed mode)

echo %JAVA_HOME%

C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_171

Running the project with Intellij works ok, but trying to run it with **mvn spring-boot:run** results with the error

I was checking and for some people the error was fixed removing the release from the pom plugin, in my case I'm getting the same error both scenarios. Tried **mvn spring-boot:run -X** do not provide more info.
As far as I know Intellij's config shouldn't affect.

Comment: The `-X` argument should most likely be before the goal/phase, so it should be `mvn -X spring-boot:run` or `mvn -X -e spring-boot:run`.

Comment: @Progman done, added full pom

Comment: Spring Boot 3.0+ you have to use JDK17+. Second you should set `java.version` to `<java.version>17</java.version>` instead of `<java.version>1.8</java.version>` also remove the whole  maven-compiler-plugin setup in your pom file.. .that is already handled by the spring-boot-parent... (See https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Release-Notes)